# Ajax Autocomplete Not Pulling Data

Tags: c#, ajax, autocomplete, asp-classic

Okay, I have searched and searched, and methods that work for others don't seem to be working for me. I am trying to get AJAX's autocomplete to work but I have had no luck. Eventually, I want a textbox with autocomplete, pulling data from a sqldatasource, but first, I just want it to work. So, I have tried a simple implementation that I found on this website. The individual who used this code got it to work using this code, but my textbox functions just like an ordinary textbox (with no autocomplete features). I am fairly new to web dev and would appreciate any assistance. Thanks.

UPDATE:
Okay...I tried making a new, simple, webpage and tried to do the autocomplete thing again. I get this bizarre result (Single characters that make no sense): 
[Incorrect Autocomplete Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jswYj.png)

### aspx code

```
 [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
        [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]
        public static string[] GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count)
        {
            string[] results = { "test", "test", "test" };
            return results;
        }
```

---

### cs. code

```
<asp:Label ID="FieldLabel" Text="Label:" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="InputField" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender 
    ID="Autocompleter" 
    TargetControlID="InputField" 
    ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList" 
    ServicePath="~/BatchReleaseStatus.aspx" 
    MinimumPrefixLength="1" 
    CompletionInterval="1000" 
    runat="server">
</ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

### Site.Master

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="CrownLabsDbFrontEnd.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title><%: Page.Title %> - Crown Labs Quality Database</title>

    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
        <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
    <webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/css" />
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />

    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style1 {
            width: 131px;
            height: 91px;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" EnableScriptGlobalization="true">
            <Scripts>
                <%--To learn more about bundling scripts in ScriptManager see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=301884 --%>
                <%--Framework Scripts--%>
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="respond" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
                <%--Site Scripts--%>
            </Scripts>
        </asp:ScriptManager>

        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    &nbsp;<a class="navbar-brand" runat="server" href="~/"><img alt="Crown Labs Logo" class="auto-style1" src="file:///C:/Users/bcampbell/Pictures/logo_crown.gif" /></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" style="padding-top:50px">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/BatchReleaseStatus">Batch Release Status</a></li>
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/CAPA">CAPA</a></li>
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/Investigations">Investigations</a></li>
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/Validations">Validations</a></li>
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/Administration">Administration</a></li>

                    </ul>
                    <asp:LoginView runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled">
                        <AnonymousTemplate>
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Register">Register</a></li>
                                <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Login">Log in</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </AnonymousTemplate>
                        <LoggedInTemplate>
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Manage" title="Manage your account">Hello, <%: Context.User.Identity.GetUserName()  %> !</a></li>
                                <li>
                                    <asp:LoginStatus runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log off" LogoutPageUrl="~/" OnLoggingOut="Unnamed_LoggingOut" />
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </LoggedInTemplate>
                    </asp:LoginView>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container body-content">
            <hr />
            <footer>
                <p>&copy; <%: DateTime.Now.Year %> - My ASP.NET Application<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script src="Scripts/currentClass.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

### BatchReleaseStatus.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="BatchReleaseStatus.aspx.cs" Inherits="CrownLabsDbFrontEnd.BatchReleaseStatus" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">





    <p><%--The following &nbsp;<p>'s keep the content from going under the Master Header --%>

    <p>&nbsp;<p>

<asp:Button ID="btnShow_ClientSide" runat="server"
    Text="show client side" OnClientClick="return false" />
<asp:Button ID="btnShow_ServerSide" runat="server"
    Text="show server side" OnClick="btnShow_ServerSide_Click" />
<ajaxToolKit:ModalPopupExtender ID="mdlPopup" runat="server"
    TargetControlID="btnShow_ClientSide"
    PopupControlID="pnlPopup" CancelControlID="btnHide_ClientSide"
    BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" />
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlPopup" runat="server"
        BackColor="#CCFFFF" BorderColor="#FF6699" style="text-align: left">
        Batch Number:
        <asp:TextBox ID="BatchNumTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Part:
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnHide_ClientSide" runat="server"
            Text="hide client side" OnClientClick="return false" OnClick="btnHide_ClientSide_Click" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnHide_ServerSide" runat="server"
            Text="hide server side" OnClick="btnHide_ServerSide_Click" />
    </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Label ID="FieldLabel" Text="Label:" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="InputField" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender 
    ID="Autocompleter" 
    TargetControlID="InputField" 
    ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList" 
    ServicePath="~/BatchReleaseStatus.aspx" 
    MinimumPrefixLength="1" 
    CompletionInterval="1000" 
    runat="server">
</ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>

    <p>
          <asp:SqlDataSource ID="BatchReleaseData" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TestDBConnectionString %>" SelectCommand=<%# ViewState["stringInViewState"] %>></asp:SqlDataSource>


    <%--Set up the stationary header for the primary GridView --%>
     <div style =" background-color:navy;  
        height:30px;width:450px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto">
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding = "0"  border="0" id="tblHeader" 
         style="font-family:Arial;font-size:10pt;width:438px;color:white;
         border-collapse:collapse;height:100%;">
            <tr>
                <%--Sets up the link buttons that will populate the header and allow sorting --%>

               <td style ="width:165px;text-align:center">
                   <asp:LinkButton ID="MfgDatLnkBtn" runat="server" OnClick="MfgDatLnkBtn_Click" ForeColor="White">Manufacture Date</asp:LinkButton>
                </td>
               <td style ="width:140px;text-align:center">
        <asp:LinkButton ID="BatchLnkBtn" runat="server" OnPreRender="LinkButtons_PreRender" OnClick="BatchLnkBtnClck">Batch ID</asp:LinkButton>
        </td>
               <td style ="width:135px;text-align:center">      
               <asp:LinkButton ID="DescriptionLnkBtn" runat="server" OnPreRender="LinkButtons_PreRender" OnClick="DescriptionLnkBtn_Click">Description</asp:LinkButton>
        </td>
               <td style ="width:140px;text-align:center">
                           <asp:LinkButton ID="BaseLnkBtn" runat="server" OnPreRender="LinkButtons_PreRender" OnClick="BaseLnkBtn_Click">Base</asp:LinkButton>
               </td>


            </tr>
        </table>
         </div>
    <div style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; width:450px; overflow:auto; height:450px; border:solid">
    <table class="nav-justified">
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center">
       <div style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto">


        <asp:GridView ID="BatchReleaseGV"  DataSourceId="BatchReleaseData" DataKeyNames="Mfg_Date" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowHeader="false"
runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="BatchReleaseGV_SelectedIndexChanged" OnRowDataBound="BatchReleaseGV_RowDataBound">

<Columns>

    <asp:BoundField  ItemStyle-Width = "150px" DataField="Mfg_Date" HeaderText="Manufacture Date"  DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy }" HtmlEncode=false >
        <ItemStyle Font-Size="Large" />
    </asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField  ItemStyle-Width = "150px" DataField="Batch" HeaderText="Batch ID"      
            FooterText="">
        <FooterStyle CssClass="FooterStyle" />
    </asp:BoundField >
    <asp:BoundField  ItemStyle-Width = "150px" DataField="Product" HeaderText="Description" />
    <asp:BoundField  ItemStyle-Width = "150px" DataField="Base" HeaderText="Base (if applicable)" />

</Columns>

</asp:GridView>
           </div>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
        </div>
    <p>


    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="BatchReleaseDataMfgDateOnly" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TestDBConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(date,[Mfg Date]) AS Mfg_Date FROM [Batch Info] ORDER BY [Mfg_Date] DESC"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="BatchReleaseDataBatchOnly" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TestDBConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [Batch] FROM [Batch Info] ORDER BY [Batch]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="BatchReleaseDataProductOnly" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TestDBConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [Product] FROM [Batch Info] ORDER BY [Product]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="BatchReleaseDataBaseOnly" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TestDBConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [Base] FROM [Batch Info] ORDER BY [Base]"></asp:SqlDataSource>


    </p>
    <table class="nav-justified">
        <tr>
            <td class="text-right">Manufacturing Date:
        </td>
            <td class="text-left">
                <asp:TextBox ID="MfgDateTxtBx" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="MfgDateTxtBx_CalendarExtender" runat="server" TargetControlID="MfgDateTxtBx" />
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="MfgDateValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="MfgDateTxtBx" ErrorMessage="Invalid Date Entered" ValidationExpression="^((0?[13578]|10|12)(-|\/)(([1-9])|(0[1-9])|([12])([0-9]?)|(3[01]?))(-|\/)((19)([2-9])(\d{1})|(20)([01])(\d{1})|([8901])(\d{1}))|(0?[2469]|11)(-|\/)(([1-9])|(0[1-9])|([12])([0-9]?)|(3[0]?))(-|\/)((19)([2-9])(\d{1})|(20)([01])(\d{1})|([8901])(\d{1})))$" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;Batch ID:
       <asp:DropDownList ID="BatchDropDown" runat="server" DataSourceID="BatchReleaseDataBatchOnly" DataValueField="Batch">

        </asp:DropDownList>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;Description:
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ProductDropDown" runat="server" DataSourceID="BatchReleaseDataProductOnly" DataValueField="Product">

        </asp:DropDownList>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
            <td>Base: <asp:DropDownList ID="BaseDropDown" runat="server" DataSourceID="BatchReleaseDataBaseOnly" DataValueField="Base">
        </asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="text-right">To (Optional): </td>
            <td style="text-align: left">
                <asp:TextBox ID="DateRangeTxtBx" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="DateRangeTxtBx_CalendarExtender" runat="server" TargetControlID="DateRangeTxtBx" />
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="MfgDateRangeValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="DateRangeTxtBx" ErrorMessage="Invalid Date Entered" ValidationExpression="^((0?[13578]|10|12)(-|\/)(([1-9])|(0[1-9])|([12])([0-9]?)|(3[01]?))(-|\/)((19)([2-9])(\d{1})|(20)([01])(\d{1})|([8901])(\d{1}))|(0?[2469]|11)(-|\/)(([1-9])|(0[1-9])|([12])([0-9]?)|(3[0]?))(-|\/)((19)([2-9])(\d{1})|(20)([01])(\d{1})|([8901])(\d{1})))$" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Red" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                  <asp:CompareValidator id="MfgDateRangeComparator" runat="server" 
             ControlToCompare="MfgDateTxtBx" cultureinvariantvalues="true" 
             display="Dynamic" enableclientscript="true"  
             ControlToValidate="DateRangeTxtBx" 
             ErrorMessage="Start date must be earlier than finish date"
             type="Date" setfocusonerror="true" Operator="GreaterThanEqual" 
             text="Start date must be earlier than finish date" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Red"></asp:CompareValidator>

                  </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender ID="TextBox3_AutoCompleteExtender" runat="server" TargetControlID="TextBox3" MinimumPrefixLength="1" ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList" ServicePath="BatchReleaseStatus.aspx">
                </ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <p>


        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="submitBtn" runat="server" OnClick="submitBtn_Click" Text="Submit" />
    </p>
    <p>


        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </p>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to use *System.Web.Services.WebMethod* in a codebehind file from an aspx Site, this method must be **static**. Also your scriptmanager need to have "EnablePageMethods=true" setted.

=> This approach is called PageMethods.

I think it's better to use WebApi instead of PageMethods, you can easily integerate this into your asp.net project. Here you will find a startpoint.
[Getting started with Web-API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api)

**PageMethod-Test:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Test() {
    PageMethods.Test(function(result){alert(result);});
}
```

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string Test()
{
  return "Hello StackOverflow";
}
```

Comment: Hm, I made the method static and I added EnablePageMethods="true" to my ScriptManager, but it still shows no autocomplete features...what could I be missing...? Let's see, I have my Script Manager on a Master Page, would that cause any problems?

Comment: This should be fine. Do you use routing ? What error you recive (browser console)?

Comment: Well, I don't get any errors, but the textbox is not functioning as an autocomplete extender. Hmm...I'm not sure what you mean by routing...don't mean to overwhelm, but I'll just show you my code in full. Here is the Site.Master: (I'll show it in the original...)

Comment: Please try to call first my posted Test - Method to make sure your pagemethods work....

Comment: Okay, I added the top code to my aspx page and the bottom to my cs. What is supposed to happen? I didn't see anything different when I loaded the page.

Comment: Call the client-function Test() and you should recive an alert if your pagemethods works.

Comment: I tried it and nothing happened...ugh...maybe my PageMethods is broken?

Comment: What error you recive ? In such situation, create an empty project, only test page methods, then search the difference if it works there.